# Load JavaScript file source code as plain text and access its content using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, xss, csrf

Is it possible to download a script file using the script tag like this

```
<script src="http://webserver.com/script.js"></script>
```

and then be able to read the loaded file content with JavaScript, like this for example:

```
var scriptContent = window.scripts[0].content;
```

What i came to notice is that the loaded JavaScript file contents is not accessible by other JavaScript files or am i wrong ?

Comment: What are you trying to do exactly ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it is not possible to do that.

The source code of a script loaded via `src` is not exposed via any API made available to JavaScript running in the page.

You could read the value of `src` and then fetch it using `XMLHttpRequest`.

The source code of specific functions may be available by calling `toString()` on them.